# How to get rid of bend marks

Tags: vertices, faces, geometry

So I'm making this stool and I decided to rotate all the faces on the legs to make this swirly effect and now I'm getting these weird bend marks, one on each of the legs. I tried messing with the vertices but I only really made thing worse. I'm not sure if there's a way to fix this or if there's a better way to achieve this look but please let me know. Here's pictures of the issue (P.S. the legs are made with cubes and not cylinders): [image: chair][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to modify the vertices, you could try the smoot tool, select the veetices in the bend and smooth them, if that dows not work you could try using the sculpt mode and smoot a little with the smoothe brush.

If it does not work a would sujest using curves with a bevel object i is usually easier to achive curvy "tubes" with them.